# React upload multiple photos via POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I am trying to post to my backend multiple photos with their name that I get from a form.
If I have to upload just one photo it works perfectly, but it does not get the name nor upload all the photos, just the first one.

this is my code so far:

```
async function handleUpload() {
    console.log("Upload pressed!");
    console.log(photos);

    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("image", photos.files);

    if (photos.length >= 1) {
      try {
        await fetch("/api/uploadPhoto", {
          method: "POST",
          data: formData
        });
        setPhotos([]);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
```

If I console.log the photos array I get this object:

[image: console.log]

I have tried mapping the format data for each element in `photos` trying to take the property `name` and saving both photos to my backend (Node + Mongoose), but I did not have success.

What would be a better approach in this situation?

Just for precision I attach also my route from the backend:

```
router.post("/uploadPhoto", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let image = new UploadPhoto({ img: req.body });
    image.img.contentType = "image/png";
    image.save();
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Comment: can you send a result of your `console.log(req.body)`? it seems to me your backend is not accepting an array of images.

Comment: I am just getting an empty object: `{}`, but in the front the console.log works, I have no idea how.

Comment: How are you trying to do that? You want to upload these files in one request like an array of files ? or you want to upload these files one by one ?
If first method show us your POST method reqest from client or postman etc
If you decided to chose second option you can store your files in some store and upload these file async